# How to stack divs in bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a navigation bar with a picture on number 1, text on number 2 div, and then the nav on div 3 (the picture is my guide).  Not sure how to put it together for number 3.

[image: Example Layout]

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <!-- split into 2 halves start centering-->
    <!-- splits to 2 columns -->
    <!-- makes number 1-->
    <div class="col-xs-6 bg-one text-center">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- makes number 2-->
  <div class="col-xs-6 bg-two text-center">
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Have another look at the bootstrap CSS documentation. You should be including row elements as well, wrapping your columns.

Comment: there is extra </div> before <!-- makes number 2-->

Answer (score 0):

For 1st image use `class="pull-left"`

For 2nd image use `class="pull-right"`

For third use `class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"`

Comment: The third class split my columns into 3 columns

Comment: Is used <div  class="col-lg-13 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might have an extra closing `</div>` in there so you're closing your header before the `.bg-two` is in there.

Hope that helps!

Comment: this should be included as a comment rather than an answer, as  it (while helpful) doesn't address the root of the question. Provide answers to questions if you don't have enough rep to comment.

Comment: Thanks Sean! Still new to this!